# Seven Sages of Japan

Tags: history, japanese

What religious order and where in Japan would there be the Seven Sages temple?
Were there 8 sages not seven?

Comment: Is your question about the Seven Sages of the Bamboo Grove? Weren't they Chinese? Could you please clarify?